# Find the size of file from absolute path

Tags: linux, centos, disk-usage

How to know the size of the file from an absolute path. For example, I have created a file test. Inside that file, I have specified the absolute paths of some other files. Now from the given file how to find the size of the absolute path?

```
du -sh filename gives --> file size
du -sh $filename gives --> current working directory size.
```

Comment: `$filename` is the content of the variable `filename`, not the absolute path to filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

We should pass the content of the test file as an argument to find the size of absolute path mentioned in it.

```
du -sh `cat test`
```

Comment: works only when the filenames do not contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--files0-from` option from `du`:

> **--files0-from=F**
>      summarize disk usage of the NUL-terminated file names specified in file > F;
>      if F is -, then read names from standard input

As I guess, that your files are not NUL-terminated, but newline-terminated, you need to replace `\n` with `\0` first. This will of course break for filenames containing `\n`.

```
tr '\n' '\0' < filenames | du -sh --files0-from=-
```

---

Alternatively, you could simply use `xargs`:

```
xargs -a filenames -d '\n' du -sh
```